# Oracle: why do I have to connect to target database for backup?

Tags: database, oracle, target, restore, rman

This is possibly a stupid question.
I have a "flash recovery area", with a BACKUPSET and a AUTOBACKUP folders containing .bkp files.
The rman documentation says that I have to connect to the "target" database, which should be "the database to be restored".Well, obviously, this database doesn't exist - that's why I want to restore it! I only have the backup files.So why do I have to connect to it in order to get rman to restore the database? 
Do I have to create a new database, connect rman to it as target, and then restore to it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to create some database instance.